# Проверка свойсва и выход из функции

Tags: javascript

Есть функция которая добавляет новый контакт в массив, надо проверить есть такое имя или нет. Мой вариант норм? Или как можно проще записать?

```js
let contacts = [{name: 'asd'}]
let newContact = {name:'asd'}

function check() {
  const sameName = contacts.map(e => e.name).includes(newContact.name);
  if (sameName) {
    console.log('true')
    return;
  } else {console.log('false')}
}

check(newContact)
```

Comment: Уберите `map` и используйте `find` [https://learn.javascript.ru/array-methods#find-i-findindex](https://learn.javascript.ru/array-methods#find-i-findindex)

Comment: @SwaD а можно как то записать чтоб оно еще и выходило из функции?

Comment: @Yaroslav выходило из какой конкретно функции?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let contacts = [{name: 'asd'}]
let newContact = {name:'asd'}

function check(newContact) {
  const sameName = contacts.find(e => e.name === newContact.name);
  
  return sameName !== undefined;    
}

console.log(check(newContact));
```

или

```js
let contacts = [{name: 'asd'}]
let newContact = {name:'asd'}

function check(newContact) {
  return contacts.some(e => e.name === newContact.name);  
}

console.log(check(newContact));
```

Comment: во огонь! спасибо!

Comment: лучше `some` - не нужно будет на undefined проверять

Comment: и может, все таки, вставить аргумент в функции, если так вызывать планируется

Comment: @splash58 точно. не увидел.

Comment: @Yaroslav обратите внимание на комменты. ну и добавил ещё вариант с some в ответ тоже

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Песня! как раз то что я не мог нормально записать